# Is there a name for a matrix which satisfies det($AA^T$) = det($A^TA$)

Tags: matrices

Suppose, following is true for a square matrix $A$:

$|AA^T| = |A^TA| = |A|^2$

Then, is it some special kind of matrix which has a name?

Comment: It's true for all square matrices.

Comment: Yes, the name is *any square matrix*!

Comment: If you had $|A|=1$, now that is special!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since for all square matrices: $|AB|=|A||B|= |B||A|$, and $|A|=|A^T|$:
$$|AA^T| = |A||A^T| = |A^T||A|= |A^TA|  = |A|^2$$
Holds For all $n \times n$ matrices

Answer (score 3):

It is true for any two square matrices $A,B$. That is:
$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\cdot\det(B)=\det(B)\cdot\det(A)=\det(BA).$$

Now, the part $\det(AA^T)=\det(A^2)$ follows from $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$ and the multiplicativity of the determinant (that was also used above).

Comment: Multiplicativity of the determinant is like the mean-value theorem of linear algebra ;-). When in doubt, use it.

Comment: @Dror:  how's the drums treatin' you?

Comment: @RobertLewis didn't have time to touch them past few weeks.. My desk at work is about to break though. Hope It's going to make it :-O